# get parent id on a nested attribute in rake seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to setup my seed like this:

```
company = Company.create!( name: 'Hirthe-Ritchie',
                           time_zone: 'Stockholm',
                            users_attributes: [{
                              first_name: 'Demo',
                              last_name: 'Memo',
                              title: 'CEO',
                              email: 'demo@demo.com',
                              time_zone: 'Stockholm',
                              admin: true,
                              password: 'foobar',
                              activated: true,
                              activated_at: Time.zone.now,
                              reviewer_attributes: {
                                reviewer_user_id: # parent id
                                }
                            }]
                          )
```

now what I want is that on reviewer_attributes, to make reviewer_used_id, the user id of the user being created.

So I have user_id and reviewer_user_id in my Reviewer model, now how do I get the parent's id in a nested attribute like I have here?

Comment: If your associations are setup correctly Rails should automatically do this for you. Can you show your models, please?

Comment: that's what I tried to emphasize, this is not the user_id this is the reviewer_used_id (it's self referential), the user_id is automatically done for me. But I want the reviewer user id to be the same as the user id

Answer (score 0):

You will have to split your code into several new/create between the related objects. Try the following:

```
user_attrs = {
                              first_name: 'Demo',
                              last_name: 'Memo',
                              title: 'CEO',
                              email: 'demo@demo.com',
                              time_zone: 'Stockholm',
                              admin: true,
                              password: 'foobar',
                              activated: true,
                              activated_at: Time.zone.now
                            }
user = User.new(user_attrs)
user.reviewer = user
company = Company.new(name: 'Hirthe-Ritchie', time_zone: 'Stockholm')
company.users << user
company.save!
```